# D3 stagger animations

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to stagger enter (and transitions but starting with enter) animations for a d3 piece I am working on. Admittedly, I don't have a great grasp on this D3, as I am just starting out with it, but here is what I am trying -

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
  .transition()
  .delay(100)
   .each("start", function() { 
      d3.select(this)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
  });
```

So, the intended effect is having each enter transition delayed by 60ms of the previous one. Kind of like if I were to loop through and do something like delay = i*60 . I would appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

d3's `delay()` accepts a function like the other methods:

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("dy", "0em")// <-- May or may not be needed
  .transition()
  .delay(function(d, i) { return i*60; })// <-- delay as a function of i
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it.  Here's an example showing @meetamit's delay: http://plnkr.co/edit/OWNmWfi4aVMUPNV1yvUO?p=preview

Comment: Sorry @Mark, that's happened to me too before... Thanks for adding the example!!